# 'Problems' in VSC not finding basic typing errors

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm writing code in Java using Visual Studio Code for a project I'm working on. I've been quite pleased with the environment until now, when the 'Problems' window seemed to stop detecting I've made basic typing errors. Right now it detects some errors, but it doesn't detect, for example, when I'm using variables that haven't been declared.

E.g. if I would just have a basic main function and run only the line "int a = 0 + foo", VSC would not detect that 'foo' hasn't been declared. Does someone have an idea about what could be causing this? I might add that I have not done anything out of the ordinary that could causes this (the best I know), and I've done 3-4 projects before without running into this problem.

I've only tried Googling the problem. Since I'm quite inexperienced in this field I don't really have any thoughts on what could be the cause of this.

Comment: What plugin are you using for the Java support ?

Comment: I know I'm off-topic, but is there a reason you're trying to use vscode for Java? There are IDEs much better suited for Java.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't typed enough code to allow the incremental parser to work out that kind of thing  `foo` needs to be; e.g. a variable, a method, a class, a package, an enum value, etcetera.  It is also possible that you have "wedged" VSC.

Comment: @Seblor I have Code Runner 0.9.7, Debugger for Java 0.16.0, Java Dependency Viewer 0.3.0, Java Extension Pack 0.5.0, Java Test Runner 0.14.0, Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat 0.38.0 & Maven for Java 0.14.2 enabled.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I'm using VSCode frankly because my partner insisted on it - he's been using it for quite a while now and has more experience than me. He however does not realise where the problem stems from.

Comment: @StephenC I listed the "foo" line as an example, I ran into this when running a larger project - and of course this is irritating whereas I have to go through all my written code to find some basic typos - e.g. if I type "witdh" instead of "width". - What happens when I "wedge" VSC?

Comment: Wedged is shorthand for "it is broken in some unspecified way".  I'm basically saying that it might be a VSCode bug.  Perhaps, since your partner insists on you using VSCode you should insist on him helping you to find the problem!

Comment: @StephenC That's one strategy!